# Запуск jar файла двойным щелчком

Tags: java, gui, windows-10, jar

Доброго времени суток.

**В чем проблема:** Есть GUI приложения написанные на Java. Приложения представлены в виде jar файла. При двойном щелчке мышью по любому из этих файлов (и любому другому исполняемому jar файлу) они не запускаются.

**На чем и с чем работаю:** ОC - windows 10. Версия JDK - 11. Среда разработки - Intellig IDEA (с её помощью компилирую исходники и собираю jar файлы).

**Как я пытался решить проблему:** Сперва я решил проверить - все ли в порядке с самими jar файлами. Я запускал их с командной строки с помощью команды java -jar JarFilName.jar и javaw -jar JarFileName.jar. Все прекрасно работало. Далее я пробовал запустить двойным щелчком мышью ***эти же*** jar файлы на других ПК, где установлена Java. Там все прекрасно работало. Для запуска jar файлов, в качестве программы открывающей файлы данного типа, на моем ПК выбрана Java(TM) Platform SE binary (на других ПК, где открытие jar щелчком мыши работало - также выбрана Java(TM) Platform SE binary).

Пожалуйста, скажите в чем может быть проблема и как её решить.

Comment: Как я помню, есть проблема с запуском когда в пути к файлу есть всякие не латинские символы, в частности имя пользователя домашнего каталога. Как это решить я, правда, не знаю

Comment: В пути к файлам и дериктории где лежит Java - нет русских символов. Я переносил его в корень диска D и в те дериктории, в именах которых только латиница. Но это не решило проблему. На компьютерах, на которых я запускал эти же jar файлы - в именах катклога, куда я поместил  jar файлы  - были русские буквы, но все работало. Эх, понять бы в чем проблема.

Comment: @Bakuard дак создайте батник, делов то.

Comment: Krychun Ivan, да батник уже создал. Просто создавать батник для каждого jar который мне нужен (а у меня их много, ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО, у будет ещё больше) - занятие так себе. Да и просто, хочется чтобы как у людей - щелкнул и запустилось.

Comment: В принципе, первый же запрос в гугле дает такие инструкции https://superuser.com/questions/1194758/unable-to-run-jar-files-by-double-clicking-them-on-windows-7, если с английским дружите. Пробовали?

Comment: Спасибо, Serhii Dikobrazko. На английском информацию искал, но эту ссылку почему-то не заметил. Приведенная вами ссылка помогла мне решить проблему. Перешел в regedit, и оказалось, что HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar в качестве приложения по умолчанию использует WinRAR. Поменял на javaw - все заработало. Спасибо ещё раз. Вопрос решен. Пожалуйста - перенесите ваш комментарий в ответы, чтобы я мог отметить его как ответ решивший вопрос.

Comment: Можно так: https://jarfix.ru.softonic.com/

Comment: Ну я в принципе не знаю что именно вам помогло. Напишите ответ потом сами с описанием что увидели, что на что поменяли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перешел в regedit, и оказалось, что HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.jar в качестве приложения по умолчанию использует WinRAR. Поменял на jarfile - все заработало. Более подробную информацию можно получить по первой ссылке представленной в комментариях под вопросом.