# Запуск jar архива двойным щелчком JDK 14, WIN 10

Tags: java, windows-10, jar

Я только начал изучать создание исполняемого jar архива из командной строки.
С помощью команды jar создал файл app.jar. Этот архив с программой запускается из cmd командой: java -jar app.jar. Но при двойном клике мышкой на этом файле в всплывающем окне "Java Virtual Machine Launcher" пишет "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again".
Я предполагаю, что это может быть из-за того, что компиляция происходила с помощью JDK 14, а двойным кликом мышки система пытается запустить программу в более старой версии.
Я читал эту тему, [Запуск jar файла двойным щелчком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962898/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-jar-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc), но не смог решить проблему.
Прошу помощи в решении этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

В системных переменных для переменной JAVA_HOME и PATH указать путь до JDK 14

Comment: еще можно использовать флаг при компиляции, если запускать надо в более старой версии http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2015-July/002414.html

Comment: Ок. JAVA_HOME указана: C:\Tools\jdk-14.0.1. В PATH есть %JAVA_HOME%\bin. При этом JAVA_HOME указана первой в списке.

Comment: JAVA_HOME указана: C:\Tools\jdk-14.0.1. В Path есть %JAVA_HOME%\bin. Это переменные среды пользователя. В Системных переменных в Path есть: C:\Tools\jdk-14.0.1\bin (первый в списке), C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath. Эти переменные установлены были изначально и при этом двойной щелчок мышки на файле jar вызывает сообщение об ошибке, в то время как из командной строки этот файл запускается и выполняется: java -jar app.jar

Comment: В cmd:
assoc .jar  -> убедиться что вывод команды .jar=jarfile
далее
ftype jarfile -> какой вывод у команды?